# Variance of the logit of the mean of the predicted values of a logistic model

Tags: logistic, prediction

I have a logistic model, and I am trying to calculate the standard error of the logit of the mean of the predicted values.

Here an example with R:

```
logit <- function(x) log(x/(1-x))
expit <- function(x) exp(x)/(1+exp(x))
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)
my <- expit(x1 + x2)
u <- runif(100)
y <- as.numeric(u < my)
df <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)
mod <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df, family = "binomial")
a <- mean(predict(mod, newdata = df, type = "response"))
logit(a)
## [1] -0.04000533
```

For the variance of this mean, using delta method and since all observations are independant, I found this simple formula:

$var(A) = var(\frac{\sum p_i}{n}) = \frac{\sum var(p_i)}{n^2}$

$var(f(A)) = var(f(\frac{\sum p_i}{n})) = f^{\prime}(A)^2\frac{\sum var(p_i)}{n^2} = \frac{\sum var(p_i)}{(nA(1-A))^2}$

```
predicted.values <- predict(mod, newdata = df, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)
sum(predicted.values$se.fit^2)/((nrow(df)*a*(1-a))^2)
## [1] 0.000894278
```

But this estimation is quite far from the bootstrap estimation

```
boot.fun <- function(data, i) {
  df <- data[i, ]
  model <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df, family = "binomial")
  logit(mean(predict(model, newdata = df, type = "response")))
}
library(boot)
boot.res <- boot(df, boot.fun, 499)
var(boot.res$t)
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.03936805
```

I would be very greatfull if someone could explain me my mistake here.

Best.

Edit (06/07/2015) : Damned, observations are independant, predictions are not. Everything's ok when I take into account covariance between each prediction.